# VBA SAP GUI recreate session after timeout

Tags: excel, vba, session, sap-gui

Maybe someone can help me with creating new SAP GUI session using VBA Excel.

Some code to understand the problem:

```
If Not IsObject(sap) Then
    Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    Set sap = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
    Set Connection = sap.Connections.Item(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
    Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
```

In most cases this one works fine. But sometimes this part doesn't work:

```
Set session = Connection.Children(0)
```

it happens for example when SAP GUI timeout occurs (auto logoff after some idle time). In that case I have:

```
sap.Connections.Count = 2
```

but

```
Connection.Sessions.Count = 0
```

Looks like the timeouted connection still hangs somewhere in SAP GUI. So when I try to connect to first session of first connection I got an error because there is no session in first connection.

What I want to do is to create new session?

I can do this by

```
 Dim sapSession As SAPFEWSELib.GuiSession
 Dim sapCon As SAPFEWSELib.GuiConnection
 Set sapCon = sap.Connections.Item(0)
 Set sapSession = Connection.sessions.Item(0)

 sapsession.createsession
```

This one works fine but it doesn't help because I still need to set the session first.

Is there a way to create session after setting the connection? Something like `sapCon.createsession`?

And does anyone know how can I use specific session using variable?

```
Set sapSession = Connection.sessions.Item(0)
```

This works fine but when I try

```
Dim SessionNumber as integer 
....
SessionNumber = 0 
Set sapSession = Connection.sessions.Item(SessionNumber)
```

it throws an error:

> Bad index type for collection access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel requires that the session number is an integer, so you can use the type conversion from Cint(). Strange that this is advised/required even when SessionNumber is defined as an integer.

```
Dim SessionNumber  
....
SessionNumber = 0 
Set sapSession = Connection.sessions.Item(Cint(SessionNumber))
```

Comment: Just got back to this and the solution is                                      
`Set sapSession = Connection.sessions.Item(Cint(SessionNumber))`

Answer (score 0):

The CreateSession command executes quickly and returns to Excel, but SAP takes a while to finish opening the new session. Thus, you'll need to make your Excel code wait.

Here's an example:

```
Const ms as Double = 1.15740741E-08  ' one millisecond, in days = 1/(1000*24*60*60)

Dim sapCon As SAPFEWSELib.GuiConnection
Dim sapSession As SAPFEWSELib.GuiSession
Dim nSessions As Integer

Set sapCon = sap.Connections(0)
Set sapSession = sapCon.Sessions(0)

nSessions = sapCon.Sessions.Count

sapSession.createsession

Do
    Application.Wait (Now() + 500*ms)
    If sapCon.Sessions.Count > nSessions Then Exit Do
Loop

Set sapSession = sapCon.Sessions.Item(CInt(sapCon.Sessions.Count - 1))
```